# Drawing view Keeps instantiating new subviews infinitely in drawRect Objective-c OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, drawrect, quartz-2d

I'm drawing an unstructured binary tree. The problem that I'm having right now is that when I build the application, it enters an infinite loop creating new nodeView objects all the time.

I'm new to programatic drawing. I know that I am committing some fundamental error that is probably fairly obvious. What is the best way to draw my tree of NSViews without constantly reinstantiating these.

Ideally, I want to be able to drag and drop the NSView nodes. I can figure that out later, that information is just in case it helps somehow.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (!hasSetUp) [self setUp];
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    DTNodeView *nodeView = [[DTNodeView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    //[self addSubview:nodeView];


    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self frame]);

    //NSLog(@"Subviews are: %@", [self.window.contentView subviews]);

    NSLog(@"Left tree height: %i", leftTree.treeHeight);

    double deltaY = (self.window.frame.size.height / 2) / ([leftTree treeHeight] + 1);
    [self drawSubtreeFromNode:[leftTree root] yValue:self.window.frame.size.height - 100 yDecrement:deltaY leftBound:0 rightBound:self.window.frame.size.width / 2];

    // Drawing code here.
}

-(void)drawSubtreeFromNode:(DTNode *)node yValue:(double)y yDecrement:(double)deltaY leftBound:(double)left rightBound:(double)right {

    double x = (left + right) / 2; // Draw the node in between the parents

    DTNodeView *selfRoot = [[DTNodeView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(x, y, 100, 50) andNode:node];
    [self addSubview:selfRoot];

    if ([node hasLeft]) {
        double y2 = (y - deltaY);
        double x2 = (left + ((left + right)/2))/2;


        [[NSColor redColor] set];
        NSBezierPath *line = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
        [line setLineWidth:2];
        [line moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)];
        [line lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(x2, y2)];
        [line stroke];

        //drawSubtree(node.getLeft(), y-yDecrement, yDecrement, left, ((left + right)/2));
        [self drawSubtreeFromNode:[node left] yValue:(y - deltaY) yDecrement:deltaY leftBound:left rightBound:((left + right) / 2)];

    }

    if ([node hasRight]) {
        double x2 = (right + ((left + right)/2))/2;
        double y2 = (y - deltaY);

        [[NSColor redColor] set];
        NSBezierPath *line = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
        [line setLineWidth:2];
        [line moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)];
        [line lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(x2, y2)];
        [line stroke];


        //drawSubtree(node.getRight(), y-yDecrement, yDecrement, ((left + right)/2), right);
        [self drawSubtreeFromNode:[node right] yValue:(y - deltaY) yDecrement:deltaY leftBound:((left + right) / 2) rightBound:right];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the drawRect method, you should draw and nothing else. It's not the place to create views and add them to their superview. It should be obvious that adding a subview means that the view needs to be redrawn, which then will create new subviews etc. etc. etc.

Comment: So should I create a method which instantiates the subviews and then in the draw method just call addSubview: on all of those?

Comment: Yes, you need to pre-create all the objects you need for the drawing previously (init, or layoutSubviews, or whatever you like) for the drawing to be as performant as possible.